# JavaFX tableView, when adding items to table A, table B take them too?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

This is such edit of an old invoice example.
I have two tables A and B,
table_A used to load all items or an item by search then select and click Add button to add it to table_B.
table_B loads the old saved items previously in an invoice.
* The strange thing is when I click All Button all button loaded to table_A and table_B too ! plus the old saved item/s of an old invoice.
* when I remove just the line of loading the old invoice-item/s and line of setting these item/s to table_B every thing works fine. so the problem in this part I hope any one explain to me.
table_A at left and table_B at right.
 *** Hint the tables works fine before adding two line of code below at first.
[image: This is a snipping of app]

```
// The code who makes unexpected issue:
invoiceList = DBForInvoices.invoiceItems(invoice.getID());
table_B.setItems(invoiceList);

// About tables
@FXML private TableView<Item> table_A;   //Table Of Search
@FXML private TableColumn<Item, String> col_s_code;
@FXML private TableColumn<Item, String> col_s_name;

@FXML private TableView<Item> table_B;    //Table Of Order Items    
@FXML private TableColumn<Item, String> col_o_name;
@FXML private TableColumn<Item, String> col_o_quantity;
@FXML private TableColumn<Item, String> col_o_price;
@FXML private TableColumn<Item, String> col_o_warranty;

private void setItemsTables() {
//  Setting columns of Search items.
    col_s_code.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("code_3"));
    col_s_name.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("name_4")); 

//  Setting columns of invoice items.
    col_o_name.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("name_4"));
    col_o_quantity.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("quantity_6")); 
    col_o_price.setCellValueFactory( 
            new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("price_7"));
    col_o_warranty.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("warranty_8")); 
}
```

Comment: How do you create the tables? Do you use the same list when you initialise them? Like in the API: `TableView(ObservableList<S> items)`

Comment: of course no, they work properly when creating a new Invoice, one list to search , other to the invoice-item/s.

Comment: Can you provide your code on how you are creating the tables, and how your are setting their values?

Comment: You don't include any of the important parts in the answer. Setting the `cellValueFactory`s certainly has nothing to do with your issue (unless you use weird subclasses of `TableColumn`).

Comment: Thank u for ur advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assume ObservableList obsList is the underlying list for the TableView.
   Then
`obsList.clear()` (inherited from `java.util.List<>`) will not update the tableView correctly but.

Also calling `setItem(obsList)` did not work to trigger a refresh...but...

`obsList.removeAll(obsList)` (overwritten by `ObservableList`) works fine because it fires the changeEvent correctly :-)

Refilling a list with completely new content then works as follows:

```
obsList.removeAll(obsList);
obsList.add(...); //e.g. in a loop...
```

or

```
obsList.removeAll(obsList);
FXCollections.copy(obsList, someSourceList)
```

Comment: I had tried such thing, but i wrote above that the problem is about unknown relation shouldn't happen.
when loading all in table_a : same to table_b
when clear all from table_a : same to table_b